# Generator to copy templates from gem to host application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to build a gem. Inside a gem I have some files which needs to be copied to host application.

So I want to build a generator which will copy templates from gem to host application to particular directory.

Bellow is my gem structure.

[image]

And I tried to run bellow command from host application.

```
rails g rfile_manager:install
```

and content of **install_generator.rb** as bellow

```
require 'rails/generators'

module RfileManager
  module Generators
    class InstallGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
      # copy configuration
      def copy_initializer
        template 'rfile_manager.rb', 'config/initializers/rfile_manager.rb'
        template 'rfile_manager.yml', 'config/rfile_manager.yml'
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Its not working and I am getting bellow message on running above command.

```
  Could not find "rfile_manager.rb" in any of your source paths. 
  Please invoke RfileManager::Generators::InstallGenerator.source_root(PATH)
  with the PATH containing your templates. Currently you have no source paths.
```

So kindly help me to in

- How to invoke **copy_initializer** method from host application to copy templates to host application or suggest if I am doing it wrong.

Comment: I think you're missing a `source_root File.expand_path("../templates", __FILE__)` there.

Comment: Yess correct, it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html), need to add class method **source_root**. This method points to where our generator templates are placed. By default it points to  **lib/generators/install/templates**.

Bellow code fixed the issue.

```
require 'rails/generators'

module RfileManager
  module Generators
    class InstallGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
      source_root File.expand_path("../templates", __FILE__)#This line added

      # copy configuration
      def copy_initializer
        template 'rfile_manager.rb', 'config/initializers/rfile_manager.rb'
        template 'rfile_manager.yml', 'config/rfile_manager.yml'
      end

    end
  end
end
```